# Ajax status code 200 but success event not working?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, ajaxform

My site working fine on xampp server. But not working on shared hosting. Response code 200 but submit event not working on shared hosting - username & pass is: mr1aminul
Function data success not working. Preview showing 2 responses on same submit.

```javascript
var bar = $('#bar');
var status = $('#status');
var publisher_button = $('#publisher-button');

$('form.publisher-box').ajaxForm({
  url: Wo_Ajax_Requests_File() + '?f=posts&s=insert_new_post',
  beforeSend: function() {
    $('.msg_progress').fadeIn(100);
    var percentVal = '0%';
    bar.width(percentVal);
    publisher_button.attr('disabled', true);
  },
  uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
    var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
    bar.width(percentVal);
    $('.tag_pub_box_progress').fadeIn(100);
  },
  beforeSubmit: function(a, b, c) {
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      if (a[i].name == 'postPhotos[]') {
        for (var b = 0; b < deleted_images.length; b++) {
          if (a[i].value.name == deleted_images[b]) {
            a[i] = {
              name: '',
              value: ''
            };
          }
        }
      }
    }
    deleted_images = [];
  },
  success: function(data) {
    alert('test');
    $('#tagPostBox').modal('hide');
    if (data.status == 200) {
      Wo_HidePosInfo();
    } else {
      if (data.errors && data.errors != '') {
        $("#error_post").modal('show');
        $('#error_post_text').text(data.errors);
        Wo_Delay(function() {
          $("#error_post").modal('hide');
        }, 3000);
      }
    }
  }
  publisher_button.attr('disabled', false);
});
```

[Image Attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6USZz.png)

Comment: What is this function returns?  Wo_Ajax_Requests_File()

Comment: That 200 is not the status of the call. It's just a random field in the payload which is called `status`.

Comment: Wo_Ajax_Requests_File() is url of the folder or directory ajax files.

Comment: You can check on sharehobe.com >My site is working fine on xampp server

Comment: "*You can check on...*" no, all of the information for the question should be *in* the question. When you finally fix problem, then visiting an external link would not be useful. Thus future visitors would not benefit from the question and the answers to it. Nor can they effectively answer.

Comment: I have send my code and write my problem on the question also attached a image.

Comment: And none of the information shows whether the request was indeed successful. Nor do you mention any errors from the console which, if I had to guess, you'd have. And if you do, it'd be because the response you get is not valid JSON, so it cannot be parsed correctly. Yet, that's just a guess, there is not nearly enough information to verify it, nor to let me guess any other thing that could be wrong.

Comment: Add (*Always*) an `error:` handler to see what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks for including the network screenshot - it looks like your service/API is returning *something* and it looks like a 200 (though as noted above the `"status":` is a property, not the response code.   As also noted above, it looks like your response is not valid JSON - notably it has `}{` which would not parse.  You could try setting `dataType:"string"` (though this isn't mentioned of the ajaxForm docs, it is a standard for jquery).  Then `console.log(data); data = JSON.parse(data)` to see what you're actually getting and if it can be parsed.

Comment: still not working after dataType:"string"